# How can i save a data on database using django views?

Tags: python, django, view

I tried saving data on database using django views but it return a error.

```html
def get_enroll(request, pk):
 user = request.user
 users = User.objects.filter(username=user)
 course = Course.objects.filter(pk=pk)
 chapter = ChapterModel.objects.filter(course = course)

 abc = Enroll()
 abc.save_enroll(users, course, chapter)

 template_name = 'dashboard.html'
 context = {'users':user,'course':course}
 return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: what is the error. Please include the error in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it directly like:

```
Enroll(user=user, course=course, chapter=chapter).save()
```

Comment: Your user, course and chapter must be their respective instance, so get the respective instances before assigning as parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
abc = Enroll.objects.create(users=users, course=course, chapter=chapter)
```

Since you havent provided your models, nor any logic of how you want this to work, I cannot give you a better solution than this one.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried as you suggested but i got this error..

Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Course: Html5>]>": "Enroll.course" must be a "Course" instance.

Comment: @AnkurBelbase well the error speaks for itself, the provided course is not a course instance, but rather a `QuerySet`. to fix this simply use `course = Course.objects.get(pk=pk)` instead of `.filter()`. Hope this helps, and may I ask you to upvote and mark the answer as accepted, so that future visitors can solve their issue faster? Thanks!